# How to close modal when <a> inside <li> is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs, simplemodal

I have managed to create a modal cum tab.

When user clicks the black color button, a modal appears with the list options. And as per user's selection content is shown.

I'm sharing the entire code below.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("modalbtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// Get the li links that will change tabs
var link = document.getElementsByClassName("modallink");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
link.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}






setButtonInnerText(document.querySelector(".dropbtn"))

function openPage(id, a) {
  const p = document.querySelector("[tab-name='" + id + "']");
  const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs .dl-tabcontent");
  for (var x = 0; x < tabs.length; x++)
    tabs[x].classList.add("d-none");
  if (p !== null) {
    document.querySelector(".dropbtn").innerHTML = a.innerHTML;
    p.classList.remove("d-none");
  }
}


function toggleDrop(drop) {
  drop.classList.toggle("d-none");
  drop.onclick = function(e) {
    drop.classList.add("d-none");
  }
}

function setButtonInnerText(btn) {
  const firstOption = btn.parentElement.querySelector("#drop a:first-child");
  btn.innerHTML = firstOption.innerHTML;
}
```

```css
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  line-height: 1.35;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 26px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
}


/* .modal-para{
    font-size: 20px;
} */

#modalbtn {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  /* max-width: 200px; */
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid;
  font-size: 17px
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 50px auto 50px;
  padding: 25px 35px;
  /* border: 1px solid #888; */
  border-radius: 12px 12px;
  box-shadow: var(--shadow);
  max-width: 500px;
  /* width: 70%; */
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  /* display: block; */
  color: #aaaaaa;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  /* border: 3px solid; */
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #e8e8ed;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72);
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-content-inner {
  height: auto;
  margin: 40px auto 10px;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.modal-title {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.modal-ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}

.modal-li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal-li:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--border-color);
}

.modal-li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--ast-global-color-2);
  padding: 17px 0;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.modal-li a:hover {
  color: var(--ast-global-color-1);
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}

.tabs {
  max-width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="modalbtn" onclick="toggleDrop(document.querySelector('#drop'))" class="dropbtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>

    <div class="modal-content-inner">
      <h3 class="modal-title">Select Option</h3>

      <div id="drop" class="dropdown-content">
        <ul class="modal-ul">
          <li class="modal-li"><a id="modallink" href="#bird" onclick="openPage('dl-tabOne', this)">Click for Bird</li>
                        </a>
            <li class="modal-li"><a id="modallink" href="#animal" onclick="openPage('dl-tabTwo', this)">Click for Animal
                        </li>
                        </a>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>


<div class="tabs">
  <!-- Bird Name -->
  <div tab-name="dl-tabOne" class="dl-tabcontent">
    Parrot
  </div>

  <!-- Animal Name -->
  <div tab-name="dl-tabTwo" class="dl-tabcontent d-none">
    Lion
  </div>
</div>
```

Things are working fine but I want the modal to close automatically when the user clicks an option.

I'm new to JS. Kindly help me with the code that will close the modal when user clicks an option.

Thanks.

Comment: You select links via `document.getElementsByClassName("modallink")` but none of your elements have the class `modallink`. You set two ids to the link elements, but id is not a class. Id can only be used once in the whole document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this statement `modal.style.display = "none";` as part of your `openPage` function as shown below :

```
function openPage(id, a) {
    const p = document.querySelector("[tab-name='" + id + "']");
    const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs .dl-tabcontent");
    for (var x = 0; x < tabs.length; x++)
        tabs[x].classList.add("d-none");
    if (p !== null) {
        document.querySelector(".dropbtn").innerHTML = a.innerHTML;
        p.classList.remove("d-none");
    }
   modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Thank you @sourav
I was wondering to add a transition as the modal is opening and closing too fast. So can you tell me against which CSS element to add a transition?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line

modal.style.display = "none";

on openPage() function

```js
function openPage(id, a) {
  const p = document.querySelector("[tab-name='" + id + "']");
  const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs .dl-tabcontent");
  for (var x = 0; x < tabs.length; x++)
    tabs[x].classList.add("d-none");
  if (p !== null) {
    document.querySelector(".dropbtn").innerHTML = a.innerHTML;
    p.classList.remove("d-none");
  }
 modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).